# Generate schema in dropwizard-hibernate

Tags: maven, hibernate-4.x, dropwizard

I followed the tutorial for dropwizard and hibernate without problems. Now I have non trivial annotations in my entities, and I would like hibernate to generate the tables for me, and stuff like that.**So, how can I change hibernate's configuration? Can I give it a hibernate.cfg.xml? If I can, do I have to set up the connection again?**

I found this [PR](https://github.com/vadims/dropwizard/commit/8fff08cc093a5214b12972abae6a73097ca4db9c), 
but it doesn't seem to be in the public release yet (no hibernateBundle.configure in my jars)

But maybe I'm looking for the wrong thing. So far, I'm just trying to **set hibernate.hbm2dll.auto**. After all, there might be an other way to **enable hibernate table generation in Dropwizard**... So, any help?

Thank you.

---

Edit: I approached the problem from another angle, to explicitly create the schema instead of using hbm2ddl.auto. See proposed answer.

Comment: I have the same issue. I think you can supply just supply persistence.xml in the classpath and it should work

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Edit: Problem solved! Doing this in the YAML config currently works: (Dropwizard 0.7.1)**

```
database:
    properties:
        hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create
```

(from [this answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/nz_hs7NkeJ0))

---

**Old answer:**

This is what I am currently using: A class that calls  hibernate's SchemaExport to export the schema to a SQL file or to modify the database. I just run it after changing my entities, and before running the application.

```
public class HibernateSchemaGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"); 
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", "user");
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", "password");
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        config.setProperties(properties);

        config.addAnnotatedClass(MyClass.class);

        SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(config);

        schemaExport.setOutputFile("schema.sql");
        schemaExport.create(true, true);

    }

}
```

I didn't know about hibernate tools before. So this code example can be used in the service initialization to act like `hbm2ddl.auto = create`.

I'm currently using it just by running the class (from eclipse or maven) to generate and review the output SQL.

Comment: Couldn't find in the docs. What is the command to generate the schema?